# Simple console.log controller action method in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

In my `application.js controller` I have the following actions:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    currentPathChanged: function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }.observes('currentPath'),
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    actions: {
        //------------------------------------------------------------
        pageBlock: function(desc_text){
            if(typeof desc_text === 'undefined'){
                desc_text='Processing';
            }
            $.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
            $.blockUI({message: desc_text});
        },
        pageUnBlock: function(){
            $.unblockUI({fadeOut:200});
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------
});
```

Since I am rather new to debugging Emberjs applications, how do I call those actions from the console?  Basically I want to confirm they work correctly and want to hook them up to child views.

I am using the [ember cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) project to build my ember application.

Current setup at the time of this post:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping to find a better answer for this, but here is how I did it. First, using the debugger output find you application view id.  Then you can run the following in the console.log:

```
foo = Ember.View.views['ember277'].get('controller');
foo._actions.pageBlock();
foo._actions.pageUnBlock();
```

The post I referenced was [Ember-JS-Best-Practices-helpful-debugging-tools](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/20/Ember-JS-Best-Practices-helpful-debugging-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of it.  When you create an instance the `actions` hash is moved to `_actions`.

```
foo = App.ApplicationController.create();

foo._actions.pageBlock();
```

Personally I usually just throw a button on the application template

```
<button {{action 'pageBlock' foo}}>Block action</button>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lorocere/1/edit

Additionally you can use the Ember Inspector to get an instance of the controller in the console really easily by clicking on the $E for the application controller in the Ember tab in the debugger tools.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

Comment: When I try to run that I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined" and my best guess is this is b/c of ember cli.  Thoughts?

Comment: Here is a repo I use for SO questions: https://github.com/chrishough/embercli-emberjs-stackoverflow

Comment: with a little modifications, I was able to tool this and post my answer.  I would like to give you credit for the close though, so do you want to rework your answer? and I will close mine + accept yours?

Comment: I'll have to grab the code and look at that, I'm interested how ApplicationController wasn't defined.  Check out the ember inspector stuff, it'll blow your mind when it comes to debugging.

Comment: I think it is because of the CLI project and the ES6 compiler.